# Is there a way to access/see all files stored in iCloud to one account?

Tags: icloud

I am aware that there is a online view under icloud.com, and there is a OS X and iPhone app for iCloud.

Why I am asking, is:

> I deleted all of my iCloud files (so I thought), and emptied the whole
>   drive. One year later, I installed 1Password on my Mac, activated
>   iCloud Drive again, and there it was: "Do you want to use your old
>   iCloud file?"

So there are hidden files which stay there, no matter what.**I thought I deleted everything, but somehow there were files missing or still there.**

> So what is the best way to view the iCloud Drive content?

Answer (score 1):

All of your iCloud Drive content will be shown here: https://www.icloud.com/#iclouddrive.

**However, 1Password does not store data in iCloud Drive**: it stores your passwords (encrypted) in iCloud Documents and Data, which is a separate part of iCloud.

To access your Documents and Data, on an iOS device: open the Settings app, go to iCloud, tap Storage, and tap Manage Storage.

You'll see a section called Documents and Data under the Backups section if you do indeed have documents and data stored in iCloud. You can edit/delete the data of each app here.

Comment: Not correct. For example, there is a Whatsapp Backup *somewhere* - because my Whatsapp can restore itself to some backed uop state when removing and reinstalling the app. But this Backup appears *nowhere*.

Comment: @Henning It's not in iCloud Drive but rather elsewhere in your iCloud account. My answer specifies that all your **iCloud Drive** content will be visible there.

Comment: Still, the main question of the original poster was how to acces/see all the data. And with the "manage storage" thing you describe, it's still not possible to *see* the data, only *delete* it. These are different things. It seems to be a fact that I pay Apple to store data, that I don't have control over myself, as I cannot check which apps store which data where exactly, and I cannot do with it what I want.

Comment: And the OP obviously didn't know the fine differences between iCloud Drive and other parts of it, and likely doesn't care if the area where someone stores his data, on his expense (Apple gets paid for it) is called drive/data/documents or foobar.